# Setting up a search function in my Django app

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, navbar

Quick question:

I made a search bar in my Django app.
It works if I type in first or last name.  But when I try AND & it doesn't work.  Here's what I have:

```
    def names(request):
      all_names = name.objects.all
      search_term = ""
      if 'search' in request.GET:
      search_term = request.GET['search']
      all_name = name.objects.filter(
          Q(first__startswith=search_term) |
          Q(last__startswith=search_term)

      return render(request, "about.html", {'all_names': all_names, 'search_term': search_term})
```

This works as far as OR is concerned but when I slide the & in place of the | it looses functionality.  I'm stumped.  According to the Django docs, & should automatically include both.  I just want to be able to type in both first and last name in the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

With the `|` Django will search in the first_name field, then in the last_name field.

If you put the `&` instead of the `|`, you will get only the results which have a first_name and last_name beginning with your string.

For example, if you type "John", you can only names like "John...  John..."

Comment: when I use & and type either the first name or last name nothing shows up.  When I use | then I can type either first or last.  I'm trying to combine it where I can type first and last and get the query.

Comment: It seems like & would combine the two right.  and the django docs just skips right over this.

Comment: Yes with `&`the both fields should fulfill the condition.

Comment: Nope.  The Ampersand just cancels both out.  Nothing shows up.  When I use OR I can choose between first or last.  Now I tried to add another grab for last name by creating a 'search_last = "" and a request.GET for that.  But I am getting the same results.  #MissingSomethingHere

Comment: @CKnight124 use ```__icontains``` for filtering then let me know if it worked. Keep ```|``` as well.

Comment: I tried both | and & with __icontains it doesn't work.  What works for now is if I just choose one field and then filter it that way.  When I use ampersand it just cancels everything out.  So in the case of my app it will just have to be first name.